# Keyerror when looping over a data frame column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, loops, for-loop, keyerror

I had a dataset, and I want to create a new data frame from a column in the original one. Chessdata is the original data frame and hizlisatranc is the one that I'm trying to create.
However, it raises a keyerror. I couldn't fix it. Can someone please help?

```
for i in range(len(chessdata)):
    a = chessdata.newtime[i]
    if float(6)<=a<float(25):
        hızlısatranç.append(chessdata.iloc[i])
    else:
        continue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can filter the df, with values in a range of value1 to value 2, so that only the rows that meet that condition are left. You can assign that to a new df like so:

```
df_new = df_old[(df_old['column']>value1) & (df_old['column']<value2)]
```

Comment: No that's not what I'm trying. Here's what I'm trying to do: if a value in the column in that range, I want to append that row to the new dataframe.

Comment: I scrapped the original response and edited to what you have told me in this comment